# First Hibernate project where to place addAnnotatedClass()

Tags: database, hibernate, servlets, stripes

Hello all
I'm trying to build up my first Hibernate project for a Web app, but i'm having some issues
Trying to find out where to place the method:

```
AnnotationConfiguration config = 
            new AnnotationConfiguration();
```

config.addAnnotatedClass(Object.class);

config.configure();

i have some java beans decorated with annotations, shel i just insert it in the same class there the bean is?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you'd call this only if you are developing a standalone application. In a Java EE environment, you'd just define a persistence.xml file (or hibernate.cfg.xml) in your deployment archive and the container (like JBoss AS) would make a @PersistenceContext (EntityManager) available to you.

In a standalone application, you'd call this in your "Bootstrap" code. The one which sets up the environment.

In "non-Java EE" web applications (seriously, who still uses that?), you'd have to resort to some "hacks", like doing some initialization during context startup (so that you won't need to run this for all requests, as it's an expensive operation).

Comment: You'll want to look at Stripersist for auto configuring and hydrating Entities, Open Session in View, etc. for Stripes in particular.

Answer (score 0):

[Partenon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731203/first-hibernate-project-where-to-place-addannotatedclass/5731500#5731500) is right, you should bootstrap JPA with a [persistence.xml](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html).

The Stripes web framework it self does not offer any persistence services. But to make life easier there is an [Stripersist](http://stripes-stuff.sourceforge.net/) extension that offers an out of the box session in view pattern (starts a transaction before the actionbean and does a roll back after the request is handled). Very good examples of how to use and configure Stripersist can be found in the book:  [Stripes: ...and Java web development is fun again](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/fdstr/stripes)

Comment: thx kdeveloper, indeed i wanted to use Hibernate in combination with Stripes, i have the stripersist.jar, jpa2.0.jar and hibernate3.jar, i dont know if i have to download other jars, the book is referring to a "sample code bundle" which does not exist. have you successfully set up Stripes and Hibernate?

Comment: To use Hibernate you will need more than just the hibernate3.jar, you should add all hibernate libraries from /lib/required and you might even want to add lib/bytecode/cglib/cglib-2.2.jar and /lib/bytecode/javaassist-3.12.0.GA.jar for some features. For using Stripes you need stripes.jar, cos.jar and the commons logging jar. You might also want to add c3po for configuring connection pooling for hibernate.